# How to manage browser history for dynamically loaded javascript application

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web, hash

I made a website that have two sidebars (leftside and rightside).

Both sidebars load content via ajax `.load()` function (leftside.html and rightside.html).

The left sidebar contains menu. I want that when somebody clicks on a menu link, it opens in the `'#mainside'` div without refreshing the page with the help of a hash function and preserve the history so that the browser's back button and 'history.back' will work perfectly.

Here is my actual code.

#### leftside.html :

```
<div class="sidebars"><div id="ls"><ul>
  <li><a href="#a.html" class="left-ajax">AAA</a></li>
  <li><b href="#b.html" class="left-ajax">BBB</a></li></ul>
  <ul class="submenu">
  <li><a href="#c.html">CCC</a></li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### mainside: (where 'a.html' or 'b.html' must load their data)

```
<div id="mainside"></div>
```

Currently, I'm using this javascript code to load content and place hash in url bar (but unable to preserve the history)

#### javascript:

```
var Anand = {
  Config:{
    animSpeed: 300,
    screenDuration: 2500,
  },
  sideInit: function() {
    $("body").on("click","#ls li >a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("body").scrollTop(0);
      var me = this;
      Aanad.Util.showLoading(function() { 
        $.ajax({
          url: $(me).attr("href").replace("#", ""),
          success: function(r) {
            $("#mainside").html(r);
            setTimeout(function() {
               Anand.Util.doneLoading();
            }, 600);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    $("body").on("click","#ls .submenu li >a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("body").scrollTop(0);
      var me = this;
      Anand.Util.showLoading(function() { 
        $.ajax({
           url: $(me).attr("href").replace("#", ""),
           success: function(r) {
             r = r + "<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
             $("#mainside").html(r);
             Anand.Util.doneLoading();
           }
        });
      });
    });
    $(window).bind("hashchange", Anand.processHash);
  },
  processHash: function() {
    hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash)
      $(hash).click();
    if (hash == "#home")
      $("#home-button").click();
  },
  windowLoaded: function() {
    if (window.location.hash && $(window.location.hash).length) {
      Anand.processHash();
      setTimeout(function() {
    $("#preloader").fadeOut()
      }, Anand.Config.screenDuration);
    } else {
      $(".sidebars li >a:first").click();
      setTimeout(function() {
    $("#preloader").fadeOut()
      }, Anand.Config.screenDuration);
      window.location.hash = "home";
    }
  },
  Util: {
    showLoading: function(callback) {
      $(".loading-progress").hide();
      $("#mainside *").unbind("click");
      $("#mainside").fadeOut(Anand.Config.animSpeed);
      setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
      }, 501);
    },
    doneLoading: function(callback) {
      $(".loading-progress").hide();
      $("#mainside").fadeIn(Anand.Config.animSpeed, function() {
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
        callback();
      });
    },
    activateMenu: function(el) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".sidebars li >a").removeClass("active");
        $(el).addClass("active");
        $("#ls-" + $(el).attr("id")).addClass("active");
        Anand.Util.silentHashChange($(el).attr("id") != undefined ? $(el).attr("id") : "")
        $("body, html").scrollTop(0);
     });
    },
    silentHashChange: function(hash) {
      $(window).unbind("hashchange");
      window.location.hash = hash;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).bind("hashchange", Anand.processHash);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
};
$(document).ready(Anand.sideInit);
```

With this code, links can load targets into `'#mainside'` and the hash function also works fine. But when I use the back button, it simply changes the current hash to the previous one without changing the page content to previous.

I also tried 'bbq' but result is '0''.

Please help me...

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at javascript MVC libraries like `backbone.js` or `ember.js` they are perfect for the kind of app you are building (they can help you develop cleaner code in large multi-state web apps like this).

In fact one of the things they both provide is a `Router` it binds hashes to events a.k.a functions.

backbone.js example:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "":                     "default"  // # 
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },

  help: function() {
    //...
  },

  search: function(query, page) {
    //...
  }
});

var router = new Workspace();

// Another way to listen to routes.
router.on("route:defualt", function() {
  //...
});

// Starts listening to the hashchange event.
Backbone.history.start();
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

http://emberjs.com

Comment: sir please can you provide me a demo of these MVC.